# What is that point in business where it is extremely difficult to generate new business/customers called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I think the title is sufficiently clear.

To add a little more clarity, if a business is performing extremely well, we generally say it has "***peaked***".

***Is there a word/phrase/idiom that implies something opposite to "peaking" in business context?***

**Usage Sentence:** (*Only tentative, answers can contain their own usage examples*)

> ABC Inc.'s Smart Phone business _______ when a recent survey showed that it sold only X(single digit) units and added less than Y (also single digit) customers in the previous quarter. It comes as a shocking surprise as the same company had sold 1 million units within the first week of its launch.

or

> Nobody is buying ABC Inc's smartphones any more. Their business __________.

Comment: I think **plateau(ed)** would work well here. "reach a state of little or no change after a period of activity or progress."

Comment: The usage examples provided in the original post reflect not a business which has plateaued, but one which has declined. The _opposite_ of "peaking" would be more like "bottoming out," wouldn't it?

Comment: I would suggest `stagnated`.

Comment: It's a bit slangy, but as the opposite of "peaked", *tanked* comes to mind.

Comment: This question is imprecise; the title and body are contradictory. Some context about the past, recent, and expected future performance of the company or its product is necessary. Some visual plots would help as well.

Comment: Based on the title (impossible to generate new customers): "plateaued", "saturated market". Opposite of _peaked_: "rebounded". Stellar launch followed by a dud: "cratered". All very different scenarios!

Comment: @200_success-The past and present are described in the usage. In the past, the company sold million units within a week. The present situation is that its Smartphone sales has decreased to abysmal proportions that it added only minuscule number of customers and sold negligible number of devices(this implies that the company is in trouble and the future looks uncertain unless they revamp or introduce new products/services). I am concerned with a word that indicates the state of business at present. What the company does to revive itself in the *future* is not the question. Hope this clarifies?

Comment: I agree - the "example" text given is **not** an example of the situation described in the title, so this is an inherently confusing and contradictory question.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - I think the word "impossible"(in title) is causing the confusion. I've replaced it to add more clarity to suit the example phrases.

Comment: @JohnClifford now that the question body and title have been changed, "plateaued" is, in my opinion, the correct answer.  You should make it an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Ordinarily I would, but I think there are so many answers now that if I did that it would just fall to the bottom into obscurity.

Comment: We only say a business has "peaked" if it has performed extremely well, **and** we expect it to decline in the future. (Or if we're looking at a past event and it did decline after the peak)

Answer (score 29):

**Saturation** works.

**Saturated market** might work even better. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_saturation)
Means that there is no new business to be made in that particular market, a real zero profit situation if the business doesn't branch out to something else as well.

**Market Pollution**, or **pollution** simply can work too, although pollution is a passing thing.

(There probably are more alternatives.)

Comment: But it's not the _business_ that's saturated, it's the _market_. Try plugging various forms of "saturated" into the blanks in the original post—the examples don't make sense.

Comment: Their business is in direct relation to the market. If it the business is saturated, e.g. the market is completely overflown with the business, then it is a business that is saturated. A business can (not so directly/indirectly) mean a market/profession, making it valid. Sure, the examples need work. "ABC Inc.'s Smart Phone business saturated when a recent survey showed that it sold only X", "Nobody is buying ABC Inc's smartphones any more. Their business saturated/has saturated." There's a good reason these expressions/terms exist as is.

Comment: This is wrong, for the reasons stated by DaveM, no idea how it is top answer.

Comment: As i clearly explained, no, it is not wrong. Show me a better fit. Also, "the examples don't make sense" Yes, they do. Oh, you have to put some effort into making it work? Not my problem, honestly, as explained above.

Comment: I think "Stagnate" is a better fit. There are many reasons why a business could be facing this problem, whether it's saturation in the market or simply some bad customer reviews. "Stagnate" is independent of the market, so better reflects the general business issue.

Comment: Stagnate is a good one, however, Stagnate implies it can be changed. There's nothing to do with market saturation, stagnation can be worked.

Effectively, stagnation can be turned over with hard work in the same avenue of business, but with saturation, there's nothing to do anymore. Or so i think. There's a reason telcos are joking about colonizing the moon/mars.

Comment: @Sakatox What does it matter if it can be changed? As you stated, saturation isn't necessarily the end of growth either (though I agree it would likely need to find a new market segment). I'm not saying saturation doesn't work, it does, but does not cover all situations. Volkswagen has stagnated, but is not saturated.

Comment: There will always be people who need new cars. There won't be people who need old-fashioned tube TVs the chinese were so apt at manufacturing, the chinese moved into a different business/market to solve that. I'm saying that the difference between solving the problem of each situation makes saturation fit better. "Is there a word/phrase/idiom that implies something opposite to "peaking" in business context?" - saturation means the absolute bottom, no turning back. Stagnation just means a grinding halt. Again, you did provide a good alternative. Depends on what OP needs.

Comment: @Sakatox I agree your answer fits the title given assumptions as to why a business can't generate new customers, but it doesn't fit either of the usage examples. Also, "saturation" does not mean the absolute bottom. As you explained, it's a situation that forces ventures into new market segments which can actually be very lucrative for first-movers. "Saturation" is a function of the market, meaning all companies are effected in the same way. Therefore, "saturation" doesn't describe the company that successfully shifts focus and so it cannot describe the absolute bottom.

Comment: Saturation is what I first thought of, but in the examples it would be the "business reached saturation point" or "reached market-saturation"

Answer (score 12):

It looks as though you are asking for different things in different parts of the question.

**1. Opposite of *peaking.*** To *peak* means to reach to  [*reach a maximum* (Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peak). Then the opposite is to hit a minimum. You can use [*bottom out* (M-W)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottom%20out). But this suggest that sales may begin to recover in the near future, as in a cyclical business.

**2. Example sentences.**  These state that sales are falling, not necessarily that they are rock bottom. So you could say business is *declining* or  [*slumping* (M-W)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slump). An [example similar to yours:](http://blog.rossclennett.com/2015/01/hays-201314-results-uk-ireland-division.html)

> Unfortunately, in the same two year period the ***Hays Asia Pacific business has slumped***, with operating income down by nearly one third and operating profit nearly halved

**3. Title.** Here one can get the impression that the business simply stopped expanding, but that sales are holding on. We can then say that business [*matured or reached maturity* (see this article](http://hubpages.com/business/The-Business-life-cycle-Establishment-Growth-Maturity-Post-Maturity) or [this other one)](http://www.inc.com/encyclopedia/industry-life-cycle.html).

Answer (score 7):

**Stagnate:** (verb) to cease developing, progressing, moving, or advancing. [Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stagnate)

> cease developing; become inactive or dull.
>
> "Teaching can easily stagnate into a set of routines."
> Google search result

Answer (score 4):

How about ***plummet***?

> : to fall suddenly straight down especially from a very high place
>
> : to fall or drop suddenly in amount, value, etc.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plummet)

Answer (score 3):

ABC's business is [***moribund***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moribund).

> moribund
>
> (adjective)
>
> 1.
>       in a dying state; near death.
>
> 2.
>       on the verge of extinction or termination.
>
> 3.
>       not progressing or advancing; stagnant:

[Dictionary.com]

Comment: Nice word! I have edited your answer to improve formatting.

Answer (score 3):

For a candidate for a one-word antonym for "peak/peaked" in the business world there’s    [**trough/troughed**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/trough)

> **trough** verb (LOW LEVEL):     to reach a low level, price, etc. before going up again:      “The economy troughed six months ago and
>   is now growing again.”

(from Cambridge Dictionaries Online)

“… [sales troughed](https://books.google.com/books?id=4TK_AAAAQBAJ&pg=PR17&dq=%22sales+troughed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinrdz_n6_LAhXDvoMKHUV3Di4Q6AEILzAA#v=onepage&q=%22sales%20troughed%22&f=false) in June 2009 and have been increasing since then.”
(example usage of “sales troughed” from ‘Business Statistics of the United States 2010: Patterns of Economic Change’ edited by Cornelia J. Strawser, via ‘Google Books’)

Just as it takes hindsight to confirm whether business has “peaked” (and is now going down), one can’t know for sure if business has “troughed” until a recovery is started and maintained; so it remains to be seen if the business you describe will remain stuck in its trough (seems very likely, alas), in which case (and regardless) Rathony’s  “hit/touch bottom” would get my vote for the term you seek.

Answer (score 2):

Though not an economist, I think that saying a business has reached a point where creating new business is "impossible" is an overstatement. Clearly a company can reach an *impasse* in deciding how to proceed with growing the business. Indeed, the expansion of a business and its market share can (and perhaps often does) *seem* to come to a *standstill*.

However, with a willingness on the part of a critical mass of optimistic employees, the business can choose to 1) reevaluate its current business practices; 2) retool its practices if necessary; and 3) plan for success and set goals for *jumpstarting* a business which may seemed to have peaked.

The word *peaked*, by the way, seems to me to be a synonym--not an antonym--for the "opposite" term you seek, for if a business has peaked, is not the implication it is going to decline unless the business takes the same sorts of steps which I've outlined above to maintain and even surpass its current, "peak" market share?

My vote, then is for the phrase "reached an impasse."

> Having reached an impasse in generating new business, Widgets Incorporated decided to reevaluate their current business practices and to retool them in ways which would break their impasse in generating new customers.

Comment: TWIMC: downvotes can be helpful when accompanied by an explanation or a question. Feel free, then. I have fairly thick skin! Don

Answer (score 0):

The antonym of *peak* is [*bottom*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottom) in business.

> the lowest part, point, or level of something

You could considr using "[hit/touch bottom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+bottom)" which means:

> to reach the lowest or worst point: '*Our profits have hit bottom. This is our worst year ever.*'

Your example:

> Nobody is buying ABC Inc's smartphones any more. Their business hit bottom.

[Merriam-Webster, McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs]